# Python reqparse.Add_arguments(Type) won't give me the correct type in my json request

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, flask-restplus

so I have a problem. My JSON data is getting sent over as a full string but its an object. How do i send an object instead of a string through my request. My reqparser is setup like this

```
search_parse = reqparse.RequestParser()
search_parse.add_argument('indexId', required=True, action='append')
search_parse.add_argument("pagination", required=False)
search_parse.add_argument("FilterCriteria", required=True)
```

and the JSON request I sent looks like this

```
{
    "indexId": [
        "testing"
    ],
    "pagination":  {
    "Skip": 1,
    "Take": 4
    },
    "FilterCriteria": {
        "HasPatents": false,
        "IsAuthor": false
    }
}
```

and my payload is built up like this in my controller

```
sovren_payload = {
            "PaginationSettings": pagination,
            "IndexIdsToSearchInto": indexId,
            "FilterCriteria": test
        }
```

The problem I'm having is that the FilterCriteria is getting sent in the json as a string so this is how its supposed to look in JSON format

```
'FilterCriteria': {'coolguy': True, 'notcool': False}
```

But what I actually get is this

```
'FilterCriteria': "{'coolguy': True, 'notcool': False}"
```

How do I get rid of these annoying "" brackets in my json request. I print my sovren_payload and there it shows me the 'FileCriteria': "{random data}"

I also realise i have the same problem with the "pagination" variable. But if I fix it for FileCriteria I fix it for pagination as well.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yeah okay, after 3 hours of struggling I found it out, should've put type=dict
I feel so stupid. My main language is C# and I only use python for AI stuff so its still new to me. Hope this helps some poor soul like me in the future :D